# Is it possible to join a VPC from outside google?

Tags: networking, routing, google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine

I have a reverse proxy instance in GCP which has an external ip, but behind it there are a bunch of backend instances that don't have external ips but are in the same VPC. The idea is to reduce the attack surface to only the reverse proxy; pretty standard stuff.

The issue I have is that it is still useful to ssh into the backend instances (for troubleshooting purposes or for deployment purposes. I'm using ansible). Is there any way I can create a network interface in my local dev machine that would have direct access to the non-public instances (in the future, a CI machine will also need access)? In other words, ssh'ing to the internal ip. What I had to do for now was to assign external ephemeral ips to all the instances just to be able to access them with ansible directly, but like I said, for the next level of security, I want to only expose the reverse proxy to the internet

I would prefer to avoid having to create a jump point instance since creating ssh tunnels for ansible to reach every backend instance seems like a mess. Normally, I guess this would sound like the job of a VPN, but i'm new with VPCs and I don't know if there's another way to deal with this requirement in VPCs in general or in GCP in particular. What is the standard practice for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four common methods to connect to Google Cloud Compute Engine instances that only have private IP addresses. This list goes from simplest to more difficult.

**Method 1: Use the Google Cloud Console**

The Google Cloud Console supports SSH for Compute Engine Instances. Go to Compute Engine. There is an SSH button for each instance.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser)

**Method 2: Use the Google Cloud SDK CLI**

```
gcloud compute ssh user@INSTANCE_NAME
```

Note: Only support Linux. Does not work for Windows.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)

**Method 3: OpenVPN Bastion Host**

Install OpenVPN on a small Compute Engine instance and the client on your desktop. This is my preferred method as my tools can network with VPCs easily. OpenVPN is free, but the instance is not. I use an f1-micro instance unless I need high-performance networking.

[Google Marketplace OpenVPN](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/openvpn-access-server-200800/openvpn-access-server)

**Method 4: SSH Remote Port Forwarding**

You can create an SSH tunnel that can then connect to any instance in your VPC. There are many examples on the Internet. This method also requires a small Compute Engine instance but you can lock this instance to only accept SSH traffic from your network (IP or CIDR block).

**Method 5: Start an IAP Tunnel (Identity Aware Proxy)**

```
gcloud beta compute start-iap-tunnel <OPTIONS>
```

This method uses the technology behind method #1 and #2. This method creates a tunnel using a compute instance managed by Google Cloud. This method does have limits (unpublished) on bandwidth. For SSH traffic this is fine.

[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/start-iap-tunnel)